# Visual Studio 2012 debug build closes and reopens every time I build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I build on debug on any project and it launches, then closes on its own after a while, then reopens again. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Try building a "Hello World" sample.  If that exhibits the same behavior, re-install Visual Studio.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out avast! antivirus was running it first in some kind of "Avast DeepScreen" mode something or other first. I'll look for how to turn it off.